# how to interpret if the coefficients of two predictors are positive,the coefficient of the interaction term is negative?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, econometrics, interaction

I have a multiple regression model.The predictors A,B,A*B are all significant. But the coefficients of A and B are positive while the coefficient of A*B is negative. How to interpret it?
(A ranges from -1 to 1, while B>=0)Thanks!

Comment: It might be interesting for you to [search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+term+interpretation) for other questions that may be relevant.

Comment: Another helpful search--the one that found two duplicates--is [interaction regression positive negative score:1 -poisson -logistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interaction%20regression%20positive%20negative%20score%3a1%20-poisson%20-logistic)